# An "obvious" claim about the Baire number of $\omega^*$

Tags: general-topology, compactification

I am trying to read "The space of ultrafilters on N convered by nowhere dense sets" by B. Balcar, J. Pelant, P. Simon.

Let $P$ be a dense in itself topological space. Then $n(P)$, the Baire number of $P$, is defined as the minimal cardinality of a collection of nowhere dense subsets of $P$ that covers $P$.

The authors claim that the inequality $\omega_2\leq n(\omega^*)\leq 2^\mathfrak c$ is obvious, but I can't see why. The second inequality holds since every point is a nowhere dense subset and $|\omega^*|=2^\mathfrak c$, but I can't see why the first inequality holds.

Edit: $\omega^*=\mathbb N^*=\beta \mathbb N\setminus \mathbb N$.

Comment: What is $\omega^*$? From the title of the paper you refer to, I would guess that it's the space of ultrafilters on $\mathbb N,$ but I thought that was usually called $\beta\mathbb N.$

Comment: $\omega^\ast$ is another notation for the remainder of $\omega$. $\beta \omega$ is just $\beta \mathbb{N}$ in another more set-theoretic notation, and $X^\ast$ is just $\beta X \setminus X$ for any Tychonov $X$. We throw away the fixed (non-free) ultrafilters.

Comment: I don't see that claim in the paper. They even mention a space $X$ in the introduction with $n(X) = \aleph_1$. It probably holds under MA($\omega_1)$ or other forcing axioms.

Comment: What page and number (theorem or equation) is it?

Comment: @Henno: Wow, that is *confusing*, since $\omega^*$ denotes the order type of the negative integers. (Generally, $\alpha^*$ is the reverse order type of $\alpha$.)

Comment: It is just above definition 2.1. Page 12.

Comment: @AsafKaragila it's usually clear when we're talking about order types or topological spaces. Or duals of linear spaces for another use of $X^\ast$.